# How to replace elements in the array?

Tags: clickhouse

I need to change `array(1,0,2,3,4,0,0,5,6,0,7)` with `array(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7)`.

My code:

```
select
   arrayMap (i-> (if(i=0, indexOf(arr,i)-1, i)), arr)

from (select  array(1,0,2,3,4,0,0,5,6,0,7) as arr)
```

But it returns `array(1,1,2,3,4,1,1,5,6,1,7)`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like pretty weird but works (remark: zero-indexed 0-value be ignored):

```sql
SELECT
    arrayEnumerate(arr) AS indexes,
    [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 0] AS arr,
    arrayMap(i -> if((arr[i] = 0) AND (i > 1), arr[(i - arrayFirst(x -> (arr[(i - x)] != 0), indexes))], arr[i]), indexes) AS result
FORMAT Vertical
```

Result:

```
Row 1:
──────
indexes:    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
sourceData: [0,1,0,2,0,0,0,3,4,0,0,5,6,0,7,8,0]
result:     [0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,8]
```